# What is the solution/workflow to make use of my functions with Numpy and Matplotlib on the example of cash amount calculations on perpetuity?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib

I would like to make a Matplotlib plot of the the amount of cash agglomerated perpetuity against time. I use Numpy for the the generation of the x axis data.

**Problem:** 
There seems to be a problem when using the functions defined below with numpy arrays. I suspect it has something to do with the fact that the functions are not vectorized, and there is a difference between the iterative and recursive function definitions. Unfortunatly, Numpy.vectorize does not solve the issue.

**Questions:**

How do I bring this example to work? And what is the best workflow to deal with such plotting objectives? Whey do recursive and iterative functions give different errors? Why does `numpy.vectorize` not help here?

**My code looks like this:**

*Agglomerated interest:*

```
def A(a,r,t,n):
"""Calculates the combined interest with initial amount a, interest rate r, times of compounding per year n and time t."""
return a * pow((1 + r/n),(n*t))
```

*Perpetuity, recursive:*

```
def P_rec(a,r,t,n):
    """Returns the total amount that has accumulated for a perpetuity with initial amount a, interest rate r and time t."""
    result = 0
    if t == 0: 
        result
    else:
        result = result + A(a,r,t,n) + P_rec(a,r,(t-1),n)
    return result
```

*Perpetuity, iterative:*

```
def P_it(a,r,t,n):
    """Iterative implemenation of P_rec."""
    result = 0
    for i in range(1,t+1):
        result = result + A(a,r,i,n)
    return result
```

Vectorized functions were creatred with numpy.vectorize:

```
from numpy import vectorize
P_rec_v = vectorize (P_rec)
P_it_v = vectorize (P_it)
```

*Plotting the data:*

```
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

plt.plot(x, A(10,0.16,x,1), 'ro',
         x, P_it(10,0.16,x,1), 'g^',
         x, P_rec(10,0.16,x,1), 'r--')
plt.axis([0, 10, 0, 30])
plt.show()
```

**Errors:**

The iterative and recursive version of the P function give different errors. I do not understand why this is the case.

*P_rec* gives *"ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()"*

*P_it* gives: *"TypeError: only integer arrays with one element can be converted to an index"*

*vectorized P_it*: *TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer*

*vectorized P_rec*: Generates a repetitive traceback due to the recursive nature of the function.

Comment: "However, Numpy.vectorize does not solve the issue" Why?

Comment: Hello Juanlu001, not sure why this happens. The P_it gives a specific error, while the P_rec traceback just 'runs out'. I have added the error descriptions into the question.

Comment: `np.vectorize` will vectorize all the arguments, including the `t` you're using in `range`, hence the errors. You will need a for loop I fear.

Comment: At a brief glance, this looks like an [embarrassingly parallel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarrassingly_parallel) problem. If you rewrite it using loops, you can easily speed it up using [numba](http://numba.pydata.org/). Perhaps you can even index the source arrays (`A`, `P_rec`) with [index arrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#index-arrays).